# Groovy group by more criteria

Tags: java, list, groovy

I have a list of hashmaps

`list=[{account:"12345"},{account:null},{account:"12345"},account:null}]`

I am grouping them regarding those values account to separate lists

`list.groupBy({obj -> obj.account}).values().toList();`

The result is those two lists:

`[{account:"12345"},{account:"12345"}],[{account:null},{account:null}]`

This is correct, but my question is, wheter I can leave the first list as it is and everytime when there is a null value I will get separate list e.g

`[{account:"12345"},{account:"12345"}],[{account:null}],[{account:null}]`

Or in other words to get 3 lists of maps intead of 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use UUID instead of null values

(groovy)

```
def list = [[account:"12345"],[account:null],[account:"12345"],[account:null]]
list.groupBy{obj -> obj.account ?: UUID.randomUUID()}.values().each{println it}
```

or just new Object

```
def list=[[account:"12345"],[account:null],[account:"12345"],[account:null]]
list.groupBy{obj -> obj.account ?: new Object()}.values().each{println it}
```

note that `obj.account ?: new Object()` will return `new Object()` for null and empty values of `obj.account`.

if you need to limit expression only for null values then use `obj.account==null ? new Object() : obj.account`